# I want to echo an array by another array key

Tags: php, arrays, function

I don't know if such a thing is existed in PHP or not .. I am a beginner and still struggling to understand

I have two arrays $num and $word

```
$num = array (2, 3, 1, 0);

$word[0]= array("one","two","three","four");
$word[1]= array("ten","twenty","thirty","fourty");
$word[2]= array("one hundred", "two hundred" , "three hundred", "four hundred");
$word[3]= array("one thousand" , "two thousand", "three thousand", "four thousand");
```

I know I can echo a value from the $word array by using `echo $word[parent][child];` 
but what I want to do is to echo back from the array $word by using the key and values from the $num array

I don't know how it is possible but I want to make a function or anything to make it do like this `echo $word[$num"key"][$num"value"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to echo all of num values but one example can be with loops

```
foreach($num as $key=>$value){
    echo $word[$key][$value];
}
```

Edit:
And if you want specific key and value then just loop $num like this

```
foreach($num as $key=>$value){
    if($key == 'desired_key'){
        $desired_key = $key; 
    }
    if($value == 'desired_value'){
        $desired_value = $value;
    }
    /*
    or put in if both
    if($key == 'desired_key' && $value == 'desired_value'){
        $desired_key = $key; 
        $desired_value = $value;
    }
    */
}
// And after loop just echo desired value
echo $word[$desired_key][$desired_value];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. But I think I want to echo just an exact value not the entire array

Comment: Then just echo `$word['desired_key']['desired_value'];` and desired key and value you can get by looping $num array @خالدإبراهيم

Comment: Check edit if this is something you need @خالدإبراهيم

Comment: thanks a lot buddy .. I just tried the 1st loop you added and it works perfect .. just as i wanted :)

Comment: Great just dont forget to mark it as answered if this solved your problem. Thanks @خالدإبراهيم

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through $num and show the $words.

```
<?php
$num = [2, 3, 1, 0];
$word = [];
$word[0] = ["one","two","three","four"];
$word[1] = ["ten","twenty","thirty","fourty"];
$word[2] = ["one hundred", "two hundred" , "three hundred", "four hundred"];
$word[3] = ["one thousand" , "two thousand", "three thousand", "four thousand"];

foreach ($num as $i => $n){
    echo $i.' '.$n.' '.$word[$i][$n] . PHP_EOL;
}
```